# Need help passing variables from one sub classes to another in scala

Tags: scala, class, oop, abstract-class, subclass

So, I've created an abstract class and have multiple sub classes extending it. One of my sub classes holds all of my methods that I need as well as some global variables and from those variables one of them is an accumulator. Is it possible to carry over the information stored in my accumulator variable into a different sub class ? If so how would I go about doing so.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this design (global variables in classes, mutable data) but you really need to provide some actual code if you want more specific help.

Comment: Could you please provide us with some code so it becomes clearer?